# Batch script not working after deploy with SCCM

Tags: batch-file, sccm

I have created a script to manage manually the windows update clean up. When i try to run as admin the below script, it works fine. i am trying to deploy it through SCCM. The script is copied in the ccmcache folder but it's not running. Any help please ?

```
@echo off

echo Config cleanmgr flag 5100.

call reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Update Cleanup" /v StateFlags0011 /t REG_DWORD /d 0x2 /f

%systemroot%\System32\cleanmgr.exe /sagerun:11
```

Comment: You don't need `call`

Comment: Hello Compo, thank you for your reply. You mean to eliminate call function ?

Comment: Yes, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Hello. I modified the script and made a test. When i run it manually it works and on the task manager i can see that cleanmgr.exe is started. I created a package with SCCM and deployed on another workstation. I noted that the same processes was started but only for a few min. During the package creation on SCCM i selected: Hidden and Run with administrative privilege